# How do I calculate Fourier series of an $f(x)$ with discontinuities inside its period?

Tags: fourier-series

I need to calculate Fourier series of:

$$\sin(x)- \operatorname{IntegerPart}[\sin(x)]$$

This seems just a common sine function, with its value set to 0 at its max and mins, so the period is just the same as that of $\sin(x)$. But however I take it, it has at least 1 (2?) discontinuities *inside* it, and I don't know how to proceed.

My only guess comes from what I've read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10162/24304):

> If you have a removable discontinuity at a point, the Fourier series
> will converge to the limit of the function at the point.

Does it mean that Fourier series will just ignore that (removable) discontinuity, and hence my answer is $\sin(x)$?

*Note: this is not homework, but I'm preparing for an exam and this exercise is from an old one.*

Comment: Is $\operatorname{IntegerPart}(-0.1)$ equal to $0$ or to $-1$ in your exam?

Comment: @RahulNarain Well I intended it as 0. But now I'm curious to know how should I proceed in the other case.

Comment: @myself: oh well now that I understood, I guess I would just have to integrate over continuous intervals and sum them up.

Comment: @bigstones : I apologize for the incorrect answer I gave and which you seem to have accepted over a year ago.  In case you care, at a jump discontinuity, like you have in your function, the Fourier series converges to the average of the left-hand and right-hand limits.  I don't know how useful this is; some people only care about the $L^2$ convergence of a Fourier series.  But I think this fact is used sometimes to evaluate certain infinite series.

Comment: @bigstones : the removable discontinuity is at $x = \pi/2$ and I am pretty sure it is the only one in a period.

Comment: @StefanSmith : I confess I don't know much any more about this matter, however I trust you and change the accepted answer, so that you can delete yours if you want.

Comment: @bigstones : mathematicians will almost always consider the integer part, or "floor", of $-0.1$, for example, to be $-1$.  Some computer languages' "integer part" function may give you a different answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the sine is negative, then its integer part, as usually defined, is $-1$.  So you have jump discontinuities as well as removable discontinuities.  You'd have to add the integrals over $[-\pi,0]$ and $[0,\pi]$.  The one removable discontinuity can be ignored; it doesn't affect the integral.